# Does DetailsList expose a callback to add more items to the list(pagination)

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I have a scenario where there are total of 150 items that we want to render, but server returns set of items - say 30 at a time.
We want to use `DetailsList`, however, we did not find any prop that can be used to update (add to) the list of items when user scrolls to the bottom of present list.

I see that `DetailsList` handles UI virtualization, however it seems we need to pass the entire set of items at the beginning only.

Comment: Not posting this as an answer because I don't really know the details of the implementation but one thing I know for sure that several teams in MS are leveraging the `onRenderMissingItem` prop by making the next call when the missing item is scrolled into the rendered pages. If I am not wrong they are achieving this by injecting one more empty item after each successful service call and this is the part that I am missing more details of each step. But hoping that might help to get you into the right direction.

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks!

Comment: I am glad it did. Mind sharing some details of the implementation in an answer for other people can leverage it?